# How to log success requests in GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-tools

I'm using `makeExecutableSchema` from `graphql-tools` and I'm using the `logger` parameter to log errors. However, the logger is never called in success requests.
 Is there a way to log success requests?

Comment: Depending on the server you are using underneath you can use simple Http Middleware for that. E.g. for express: https://npms.io/search?q=express+log